# How to present a Graphic and a Table in close proximity to each other

Tags: manipulate

Often, with a `Plot` or within `Manipulate` I want to display a graph and, in close proximity to it, a table showing the results of relevant computations. The quickest way to do this is with `GraphicsColumn`, but that always seems to create cells of identical height and width, which is usually not what I want. Here is a trivial example:

```
Manipulate[
 GraphicsColumn[{Plot[Sin[x + c], {x, 0, 2*Pi}], 
   TableForm[{{c}}, TableHeadings -> {{"c"}, {"value"}}]}], {c, 0, 3}]
```

[image: GraphicsColumn makes me sad]

Is there some other convenient way to place the table below the graph without an ocean of whitespace, or a way to specify that GraphicsColumn can use cells of differing size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a normal `Column`:

```
Manipulate[Column[{Plot[Sin[x + c], {x, 0, 2*Pi}], Style[
    TableForm[{{c}}, TableHeadings -> {{"c"}, {"value"}}],
    FontFamily -> "Times"]},
  Center, 1], {c, 0, 3}]
```

`Column`s second argument lets you choose the alignment and the third one sets the spacing between elements. I also wrapped the `TableForm` into a `Style[...]` to change the font from `"Courier"` to `"Times"`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In some cases you might also want to insert the table within the figure using `Epilog` and `Inset`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x + c], {x, 0, 2*Pi},
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Style[
     TableForm[{{c}}, TableHeadings -> {{"c"}, {"value"}}], {Large, 
      Bold}], {5, .5}]], {c, 0, 3}]
```

[image]